# Get immutable system language list in iOS

Tags: ios, localization

If I use `[NSLocale preferredLanguages]` or `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"]`, the system will return a list of languages. However, this list can be changed by my app (without affecting the rest of the OS). Is there a way to get (a copy of) the actual global list that apps cannot change?

The purpose of this is to be able to override the language settings of the phone for my app, but also be able to revert back to the original settings. Without having access to the immutable global list of languages, I am not able to revert back again (especially if the user changes their language preferences). If I can get the immutable list, I can simply do something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *systemLanguages = [[someClass getImmutableSystemLanguages] mutableCopy];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if (overrideLanguage {
    [systemLanguages insertObject:@"languageCode" atIndex:0];
}

[defaults setObject:[systemLanguages copy] forKey"AppleLanguages"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Comment: Why can't you create a separate NSUserDefaults key to store your modified array of languages? If `overrideLanguage` is `true` then just use this key, otherwise use "AppleLanguages" key.

Comment: As far as I know, NSLocalizedString and other language related features will only use the "AppleLanguages" key.